# How do I set my eclipse project build so that other projects cannot see files in src/test/java folders?

Tags: eclipse, maven, projects, m2eclipse

I'm using eclipse with the m2eclipse plugin. I create my projects as maven projects, create the pom, and run m2eclipse on the projects to enable workspace dependency resolution. When its time to deploy, I simply export my web project as a WAR file.

One problem I've noticed is that I need the files in src/test/java to run my unit tests manually. I also put a logback-test.xml file in src/test/resources. However when I run my web apps from eclipse wtp, my web project will pick up the logback-test from one of my dependent parent projects. Is there any way to hide the src/test files from other projects, while still being able to run the unit tests in those projects manually?

Answer (score 0):

There's incompatibility between Eclipse and Maven.
I think you should read more about m2eclipse.

Secondly try to use only Eclipse or Maven tools (so you have 2 option to try).
3rd, try to inspect .war you have.